# addthis sending forever pending requests

Tags: google-chrome, request, addthis

Live page in question:http://nyaii.com/s/index.php?option=com_preachit&view=study&id=200:&Itemid=179
[image]

When open in chrome, this page forever shows "sending request" in status bar and loading  icon in page title. It is not happening every time but it is more than often. In network panel I see two pending requests which seem related to Addthis. Anyone encountered this too? What is the cause and solution?

Answer (score 0):

I went to your site, but I'm seeing our buttons without any issues.  Are you still experiencing this issue? If so, please let me know what browsers you are seeing this in.

Certain browser extensions, such as an ad blockers, may also cause our tools to not appear on the page. I'd suggest opening your site in a Private Browsing or Incognito window to see if the issue persists.

Thanks,
Elsa.

Comment: We're having the same problem... http://beta1.etesters.com/see/light/ (addthis btns show when clicking a share link in a search result) - as @shenkwen indicates, it doesn't happen every time, but more often than not it is happening. When I view incognito, it doesn't happen at all. I don't have any ad blockers running.

Comment: Yes I think it is related to chrome extensions. First I open the page in incognito mode and it works fine. Then I go back to the normal mode and look at my extensions, the only one I think is possibly the cause is "clear cache", I disable it and restart chrome, the problem doesn't happen and so far so good.